# Getting Multiple Values from a CSV and using them in a For Loop

Tags: csv, powershell, variables, for-loop

I'm new to PowerShell, so I'm still getting used to the way variables and for loops are used, but I'd just like to have someone double check my script. I haven't run it yet, as it uses a set command and I'd rather be doubly sure the code works before testing. Once I get some input I'll run a very small number of users through it. The code is for assigning users intercall numbers.

I'm using an excel file that has 4 columns. The columns are labled "userprofilename", "RPTF", "RPTOLL", and "RPConfCode", same as the variables. Here is my code:

```
$accounts = ipcsv 'C:\Powershell-dest\intercall-numbers.csv'

$accounts | % {
$userprofilename = $_.userprofilename
$RPTF = $_.RPTF
$RPTOLL = $_.RPTOLL
$RPConfCode = $_.RPConfCode
Set-CsUserAcp -Identity $userprofilename -Name "InterCall" -Domain example.com -TollNumber $RPTOLL -TollFreeNumbers $RPTF -ParticipantPasscode $RPConfCode -Url http://www.intercall.com/l/dial-in-number-lookup.php}
```

I'll of course change "example.com" to the actual domain when I run it. Am I declaring/using the variables correctly?

Comment: This is a CSV and not excel so I changed the tags and title to suit.

Comment: Are you actually having a problem? This _looks_ fine other then there is no need to save temp variables. You can just use the `$_.Property` directly when you call the cmdlet. Unless of course you use them somewhere else in your code.